# overflow short int in language C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that show short int overflows in C. In my program you enter two short int and I add them. If the addition is superior to 32767 we have a negative overflow and if the addition is inferior to -32678 we have a positive overflow.

Now my problem is that my program refuses to respect any of the condition when using `if`. But when I use `do while` my program consider that I respect the two condition at the same time.

```
short int n1, n2, somme;
printf("Enter the first number: ");
scanf("%hi", &n1);
printf("enter the second number : ");

scanf("%hi", &n2);

somme= n1 + n2;
    do
    {
    printf("negative overflow\n");
    }while (somme>32767);
    do
    {
    printf("negative overflow\n");
    }while ( somme<-32768);

printf("the result is %hi", somme);
```

Sorry for my english.  and thanks for reading, please help.

Comment: Did you mean to use `if` and not `do...while` ?

Comment: Do you understand how `do while` works? It isn't an alternate to `if`. The code in the block will be executed once, even if the while condition isn't satisfied. So " But when I use do while my program consider that I respect the two condition at the same time.", is wrong. Your program is logically incorrect.

Comment: I tried with "if" but it doesn't work .

Comment: if (somme>32767)                                                                        { printf("negative overflow");          } // it doesn't work do you think it is a syntaxe error

Comment: btw, signed integer overflow in C/C++ is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes in your code to demonstrate what you were trying to do,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    short int n1, n2, somme;
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%hi", &n1);
    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%hi", &n2);

    somme = n1 + n2;
    if( (n1 + n2) > 32767)
        printf("negative overflow\n");
    else if ( (n1 + n2) < -32768)
        printf("positive overflow\n");

    printf("int addition result is %d\n", n1 + n2);
    printf("short addition result is %hi\n", somme);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output,

```
Enter the first number: -20000
Enter the second number : -20000
positive overflow
int addition result is -40000
short addition result is 25536
-----------------------------
Enter the first number: 20000
Enter the second number : 20000
negative overflow
int addition result is 40000
short addition result is -25536
```

---

So, what was wrong in your code is that,

- You were using `do...while` to check for conditions. Use [if-else](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/if_else_statement_in_c.htm).
- You were storing the sum in `short` and comparing that with `-32768` and `32767`. You are trying to check if your sum overflowed by comparing it with values which are outside the range of values it can hold. This is also explained by [Jérôme Leducq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986116/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-leducq) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33495486/4042839).

Comment: thank you very much i think the difference is when You use if ((n1+n2)<32...) instead of if (somme<32.....)

Comment: @AmaraDiagana Correct ! `(n1 + n2)` evaluates to an `int` and not a `short`. Thus, the comparison works as expected.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `int` is larger than `short`, nor that `short` is 16 bits. Generally, you shouldn't be making weird assumptions like this, use the `stdint.h` types instead.

Comment: The "negative overflow" and "positive overflow" can never happen without the program exhibiting undefined behavior, and a compiler may well omit them.

Comment: @PaulHankin Do I really have to mention that to a person who still confuses `if-else` and `do..while` ? I intentionally avoided that. Talking about all this at this stage, I believe, will only make it harder for him.

Comment: @Lundin Do I really have to mention that to a person who still confuses `if-else` and `do..while` ? I intentionally avoided that. Talking about all this at this stage, I believe, will only make it harder for him.

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar Yes I think so. Most beginners would benefit from never using `short`, `int` etc but instead the `stdint.h` types. Because that would force them to _think_ when declaring a variable: do I need signed or unsigned? What is the maximum value I need this variable to contain? Do I need to implement limits for max/min values? And so on, very fundamental stuff.

Comment: @Lundin Thought I am against mentioning this, I will add some of it as you say. Let's wait for Paul's comment on this.

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar The code in your answer is wrong in the sense that if `n1+n2` overflows a short its behavior is undefined. A compiler may well rewrite it to: `printf("int addition result is %d\n", n1+n2); printf("short addition result is %d\n", n1+n2);` (omitting the "overflow tests" entirely) on the assumption that `n1+n2` can never legally overflow a short. This may produce seemingly paradoxical output where the "short addition result" can appear to be larger than a short could possibly contain, but that's undefined behavior in C for you.